Inversion theorem implication
So, consider inversion theorem in the form $\forall a, b : P(\xi \in \{a, b\}) = 0 \Rightarrow P(\xi \in [a, b]) = \lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-T}^T \frac{e^{-iat}-e^{-ibt}}{it} \phi_{\xi}(t)dt$, where $\phi_{\xi}(t)$ is characteristic function of $\xi$. In my lectures it was said that it immediately implies that if $\phi$ is absolutely integrable (i.e. $\int_{R} |\phi_\xi(t)| dt < \infty$), then $\xi$ is absolutely continuous.
It was "proved" by defining density function $p_\xi(x) := \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{R} e^{-itx}\phi_\xi(t)dt$ and stating that $\int_{R} \frac{e^{-iat}-e^{-ibt}}{it} \phi_{\xi}(t)dt$ is absolutely convergent since $ \frac{e^{-iat}-e^{-ibt}}{it}$ is bound. Then checking that $\int_a^b p_\xi(x)dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_a^b\int_R e^{-itx}\phi_\xi(t)dtdx = \text{[by Fubini theorem]}=  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_R\int_a^b e^{-itx}\phi_\xi(t)dxdt = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_R\frac{e^{-iat}-e^{-ibt}}{it} \phi_{\xi}(t)dt$.
And then saying that by inversion theorem it's $P(\xi \in[a,b])$. Thus, $p_\xi$ really is density function. But in this case i don't understand how can we use inverse theorem for arbitrary a and b since we do not yet know that $P(\xi = a), P(\xi = b) = 0$.
Can you please help me to proceed? I havn't found a clear proof yet and also this isn't a homework task.
